# Moving CCNode with constant speed in cocos2d

Tags: physics, game-mechanics, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I want to **move the object** (CCNODE) with **constant speed** in **any direction** , what i have did till now is applied a force to object at start to get it moving and set elasticity as 1 and friction as 0 to every object which it will collide .

After some time speed goes on increasing , is there any way so i can check if speed increased so that i can control it or to apply velocity instead of force .  Thanks !

Comment: what about adding CCMoveBy action? wrapped inside CCRepeatForever?

Comment: Problem in this is when the CCNode collide with some other node it does not change the direction .It continue to move in same direction. Is there any way to change the direction ?

Comment: Why not set CCNode.physicsBody.velocity, does that not fit your requirements?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the velocity in your update function and set it to some max value if the calculated value will be greater than that max. This way you still use force and allow it to stop when it collides with another object, but it will never be able to go faster than the maximum velocity you set.

Answer (score 1):

Just slow it down or speed it up with a force proportional to the error.

If your intentions were to hit a certain position for your object, you would actually need something more advanced like a [Proportional Integral Differential Controller](http://ps3computing.blogspot.ca/2013/03/proportional-integral-differential.html).

But if you merely aim for a certain velocity, not a certain position, then its quite easy by setting a force each frame.